# Devise sign in form in rails application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The typical form structure (within the User views) is as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

I would like to implement the sign in form in my application layout, and the above code does not work do to lack of resource at home page level (I'm assuming that's why).

The following code works, but is it correct?

```
 <%= form_for User.new, :url => session_path(User.new), :html => { :class => 'navbar-form pull-right', :style => 'margin-right:15px' } do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example in the Devise wiki:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

Comment: Thanks Tom. I didn't look hard enough.